# Magento manual uploading of product- image issue is child item

Tags: product-images, parent-child-theme

I have uploaded a product having red & Yellow color. Parent item has yellow color image, when we select red swatch child image is not changing even its image is uploaded in the backend

Answer (score 1):

I think, you have not done correct image settings in product edit at admin.

Please refer this detailed post and do compare settings you did. [Manage Configurable Swatches](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-add-and-manage-configurable-swatches.html#gref)

Try this and let me know if you still have this issue.